# logical drive letters are not displaying

Tags: c++, c

I have written a small program that will search for all logical drives in my PC and then prints them. But differnt wirh my expected, it is not displaying them.. here is my code sample

```
TCHAR szDrive[] = (" A:");    
DWORD drive = GetLogicalDrives();
printf("The bitmask of the logical drives in hex: %0X\n", drive);
printf("The bitmask of the logical drives in decimal: %d\n", drive);
if(drive == 0)
    printf("GetLogicalDrives() failed with failure code: %d\n", GetLastError());
else
{
    printf("This machine has the following logical drives:\n");
    while(drive)
    {
    // Use the bitwise AND, 1â€"available, 0-not available
    if(drive & 1)
        printf("%S ", (const char *)szDrive);
    // increment, check next drive
    ++szDrive[1];
    // shift the bitmask binary right
    drive >>= 1;
}
printf("\n ");
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged your code to determine what's wrong?

Comment: yes i did..and nothing is wrong with my code according to debugger

Comment: whats the output? whats error?

Comment: There's _nothing_ in that code that appears to be C++.

Comment: @paxdiablo It's all C++.

Comment: People who claim `printf` is C++ are, at best, only partially C++ programmers :-) It may _work_ but it's not committing yourself to the C++ paradigms.

Comment: @paxdiablo `printf` is valid C++. It's not the best way to produce output. If you look at the asker's other question, you can see what you would describe as C++. This code is just a quick test of this Winapi function. Clearly asker is using C++. Tagging the Q both C and C++ seems wrong though.

Comment: @user2660085 Not to try to be a pain, but when you debugged this you should have found the problem in a few seconds by inspecting the variables to see that szDrive was properly populated but the printf was not working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your printf statement is broken. Use this:

```
printf("%s ", szDrive);
```

I guess your use of `%S` instead of `%s` was just a typo.